# Problemas al llamar un método desde otra clase

Tags: c#, visual-studio, class

Estoy intentando hacer un programa con un switch que llame a diferentes métodos de otras clases, pero me sale este error al llamar al método "Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error CS0201 Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement Repaso progra C:\Users\a\source\repos\Repaso progra\Program.cs 29 Active"

```
    using Repaso_progra;
    using System;
    
    internal class Program

{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int opción;

        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Selecciona el ejercicio a demostrar");
            Console.WriteLine("1: Primera aplicación Curso C#");
            Console.WriteLine("2: ");
            Console.WriteLine("3: ");
            Console.WriteLine("4: ");
            Console.WriteLine("5: ");
            Console.WriteLine("6: ");
            Console.WriteLine("7: ");
            Console.WriteLine("8: ");
            Console.WriteLine("9: ");
            Console.WriteLine("10: ");
            Console.WriteLine("Presiona 0 para salir");
            opción = (int)Convert.ToUInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            switch (opción)
            {
                case 1:
                    Primera_aplicación_Curso_C_ caso1 = new Primera_aplicación_Curso_C_();
                    caso1.HolaMundo;
                    break;
                case 2:

                    break;
                case 3:

                    break;
                case 4:

                    break;
                case 5:

                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Elija una opción disponible");
                    break;
            }
        } while (opción != 0);
    }
}
```

Este es el código de la clase que alberga el método al que intento llamar en el caso 1 del switch

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Repaso_progra
{
    public class Primera_aplicación_Curso_C_
    {

        public void HolaMundo()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hola mundo");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Creo que te faltan los parentesis. Es `caso1.HolaMundo()`

Comment: Justamente era eso jaja, VS me marcaba soluciones totalmente diferentes

Comment: Por cierto, procura no llevar acentos o caracteres especiales al nombrar tus variables o clases...

Comment: de paso, no conviertas dos veces lo mismo "(int)Convert.ToUInt32(Console.ReadLine());" estas convirtiendo a entero y luego casteando a entero.. no tiene sentido...

Comment: @gbianchi en realidad hay una sutil diferencia. Primero convierte a uno sin signo y luego otro con signo. Que mejor use `Convert.ToInt32` si quiere el signo.